# What does #> operator mean in Scala Lift?

Tags: scala, operators, lift

Studying Lift I've immediately found a non-familiar #> operator. What exactly does it mean?
Example:

```
/**
* Put the messages in the li elements and clear
* any elements that have the clearable class.
*/
def render = "li *" #> msgs & ClearClearable
```

I can read the comment to know what's the line for, but am not sure about the code mechanics here.

Comment: I thought the # is for comments ?

Comment: @Ivan Pay attention, most "operators" in Scala are defined in libraries and are not part of the language itsefl.

Comment: @paradigmatic I understand, but suppose there is to be (usually) a common logical meaning for an operator.

Comment: Not that much except for those used in Scala Colections (like `++`, `+:`) or using the `!` to sent a message.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The operator `#>` is used to create [CSS Selector Transformers](http://simply.liftweb.net/index-7.10.html).

You provide a CSS selector as a string and then apply it to the given argument which can be a sequence, a string or a `NodeSeq` and get a function of type `NodeSeq => NodeSeq` that applies the transformations. The `&` is used to chain those transformations.

Answer (score 2):

There is no operator in Scala, and hence, there is no #> operator.

What looks like an operator is a method, and if it is a method, it isn't `in Scala` but in `a class`. On Smalltalk, you would say, that you can send the object a #> - message.

Since the object on the right is a String, and String does not have a `#>`-message, there must be an implicit in scope, which takes a String, and transforms it into an object, which has such a method.

Implicits are only searched for in the code itself or directly imported code, not in code imported from imported code, so it shouldn't be too much work, to search for `#>`. Maybe your IDE can tell you, where it is defined.